# Reverse proxy does not work on Apache in Cent OS 6.9

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, virtualhost, reverse-proxy, centos6

I created the **sites-available** and site-enabled folders, I added the **site.domain.com.conf** file with a virtualhost in my domain **site.domain.com** to do reverse proxy in a **Nuxt node.js application**, which is running successfully on localhost:3000. I made the following configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site.domain.com
    ServerAlias www.site.domain.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog /home/user01/site.domain.com/error.log
    CustomLog /home/user01/site.domain.com/access.log combined

    ProxyRequests off
    <Proxy *>
     Require all granted
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/ retry=1 acquire=3000 timeout=3000 keepalive=off
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyTimeout 3000
    ProxyVia full
</VirtualHost>
```

I also added the following line in the **httpd.conf** file

```
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

And after restarting apache it created the **requests.log and access.log** files in the folder I configured in the ErrorLog and CustomLog parameters, so the configuration was read by apache.

When accessing the domain site.domain.com it does not point the requests to localhost: 3000, it just displays the directory files in the browser, what am I doing wrong?

Server settings:

- CentOS 6.9
- Apache 2.4.39
- Enabled modules: proxy_module, proxy_http_module, lbmethod_byrequests_module, proxy_balancer_module

This is the result of the apachectl -S command:

```
port 80 namevhost site.domain.com (/etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf:761)
                 alias www.site.domain.com

port 443 namevhost site.domain.com (/etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf:1881)
                     alias www.site.domain.com


*:80                   site.domain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/site.domain.com.conf:1)
```

Notice that my virtual host configuration was added to the end, but still shows two other default settings, is it normal?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by following the excellent cPanel documentation, I hope it can help someone else. Remembering that the includename.conf files can not count the VirtualHost tag, just the content inside it.

https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/EA4/Modify+Apache+Virtual+Hosts+with+Include+Files